# Spark: huge number of thread get created

Tags: apache-spark

Spark version 2.1   Hadoop 2.7.3
I have a spark job, only has 1 stage and 100 partitions, my application itself doesn't create any thread. but after I submit it as

```
spark-submit --class xxx --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 7 --executor-core 1 ./my.jar
```

I found on every server, it uses about 400 threads, why so many threads are being used? The cluster has 6 servers. so one of the servers get 2 executors, and that use about 800 threads in spark process. when I actually run this. I give it a lot of cores and get a "cannot create native thread" error after system using 32,000 threads, which is the limit from system `ulimit` setting. even I can assign less core and get around this error, using so many threads won't be efficient anyway, can someone gives some hints?

updated.

it's the connection to hbase causing the problem, not spark using those threads.

Comment: How do you see it's using this much threads? Could you provide some code or the cluster configuration, because otherwise we're clueless.

Comment: ps -efL |wc -l give me all the thread in the system. and I trace down the process spark job is using, I see every single one use about 400 thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scheduler XML configuration in conf directory

- Check the scheduler used
- Check the weight configured

If there is no pool set, try setting a pool

```
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "test")
```

configure the following values

```
<pool name="test">
     <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
     <weight>1</weight>
     <minShare>2</minShare>   
</pool>
```